# What is a NavMesh in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I want to know about the `NavMesh` present in Unity3d. Why is it used? What features does it provide to a game developer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navmeshes are normally used in pathfinding. These are a type of data structure which are designed to finding a path between some objects over a large space. [See this link for a more thorough description](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html) and its [usage in Unity3d](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMesh.html).

Answer (score 0):

A navigation mesh or navmesh is an abstract data structure is used in artifical intelligence application aids to agent to find path in the complicated spaces is called navmesh